# How can I retrieve images from MySQLI database when searching for a name/product/etc

Tags: php, search

I am a beginner and am currently working on a search function, where you retrieve images from the database if you search for something e.g. Products, but unfortunately this seems to exceed my capicity.

I have been looking for a solution the whole day but couldn't find anything helpful at all. I tried to inform myself a little bit and found out that it's not recommendable to store your image in a database, is it possible to store the path?

I hope you can help me out of this!

How can i display the images with the products name if they search for it?

Edited:  image path: 
images/product.php (thats how it's stored in database)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198405/discussion-on-question-by-racpe-paul-how-can-i-retrieve-images-from-mysqli-datab).

Answer (score -3):

I hope this code help you. Any more help feel knock me.

```
<?php
    //if isset $_GET['search']
    if(isset($_GET['search']))
        {
            $conn = new mysqli('server','dbuser','password','dbname');
            if($conn->connect_error)
                {
                    echo "Connection Error".$conn->connect_error;
                }
            $searchText = $_GET['search'];
            $SEARCH = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE title LIKE '$searchText'";
            $result = $conn->query($SEARCH);
            if($result->num_rows > 0)
                {
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                        {
                            $id = $row['id'];//No place where you use $id then not need create this variable
                            $title = $row['title'];
                            $link = $row['link'];
                            $output .= '<a href="'.$link.'"><h3>'.$title.'</h3> </a>';
                        }
                }else 
                    {
                        echo "<h2>No Results!</h2>";
                    }
            echo "$output";//Rememmer it php echo faster than php print


        }

    ?>
```

Comment: do not post your answer without a complete explanation and proper understanding of the question.